# How to save image inside a specific folder(folder name should be id)-DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to save image inside folder name same as id. Id is a automatic primary key.I tried that when i give post request i  got none as a id. how can i achieve this????

models.py

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'organization/{instance}/logo/{filename}'.format(filename=filename,
                                                            instance=instance.pk)


class Organization(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    logo_filename = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to=upload_to, null=True)
```

I know i cant take id before saving into db. there is any possible to do rename when i gave post request?? I got confused over this. Any help appreciable,...

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure of my answer but you can try -

use nested models, if you can -

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, unique=True)
    ---
    ---
   
class OrganizationImage(models.Model):
    def upload_to(instance, filename):
        return instance.organization

    organization= models.OneToOneKey(Organization)
    logo_filename = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
```

And in create method of Organization -

```
Organization_Image= validated_data.pop(organization_image_data)
organization= Organization.objects.create(validated_data)
O = OrganizationImage.objects.create(organization=organization, **Organization_Image)
```

Comment: I understand that. But image upload should be in same model. If there is any possible to overwrite or anything else???